# calling function in python tic tac toe game

Tags: python-2.7

Very new to programming and would like help with my code. check_game() turns row1check to True when it is filled. Then then end game should start but it doesn't. I've put in print statment to prove that row1check does change to true.

Thank you for your help.

```
   matrix =[]

   row1 = [" ", " ", " "]
   row2 = [" ", " ", " "]
   row3 = [" ", " ", " "]
   row1check = False
   row2check = False
   row3check = False

def draw_matrix ():
   print row1
   print row2
   print row3

def check_game () :
   if not " " in row1:
      row1check = True
      print row1check
   if " " not in row2:
      row2check = True
   if " " not in row3:
      row3check = True


def end_game() :
   if row1check == True:
       print "End of Game!"
   else:
       print "Keep going"


def x_turn ():
  while end_game != 3 :
    move = raw_input("Player X Enter coordinates 'row,col': ")

    row = move[0]
    column = move[2]

    if row == "1" and column == "1" and row1[0] == " ":
        row1[0] = "x"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        o_turn()
    if row == "1" and column == "2" and row1[1] == " ":
        row1[1] = "x"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        o_turn()
    if row == "1" and column == "3" and row1[2] == " ":
        row1[2] = "x"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        o_turn()
    if row == "2" and column == "1" and row2[0] == " ":
        row2[0] = "x"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        o_turn()
    if row == "2" and column == "2" and row2[1] == " ":
        row2[1] = "x"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        o_turn()
    if row == "2" and column == "3" and row2[2] == " ":
        row2[2] = "x"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        o_turn()
    if row == "3" and column == "1" and row3[0] == " ":
        row3[0] = "x"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        o_turn()
    if row == "3" and column == "2" and row3[1] == " ":
        row3[1] = "x"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        o_turn()
    if row == "3" and column == "3" and row3[2] == " ":
        row3[2] = "x"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        o_turn()
print "End of Game!"

def o_turn ():
  while end_game != 3 :
    move = raw_input("Player O Enter coordinates 'row,col': ")

    row = move[0]
    column = move[2]

    if row == "1" and column == "1" and row1[0] == " ":
        row1[0] = "O"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        x_turn()
    if row == "1" and column == "2" and row1[1] == " ":
        row1[1] = "O"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        x_turn()
    if row == "1" and column == "3" and row1[2] == " ":
        row1[2] = "O"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        x_turn()
    if row == "2" and column == "1" and row2[0] == " ":
        row2[0] = "O"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        x_turn()
    if row == "2" and column == "2" and row2[1] == " ":
        row2[1] = "O"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        x_turn()
    if row == "2" and column == "3" and row2[2] == " ":
        row2[2] = "O"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        x_turn()
    if row == "3" and column == "1" and row3[0] == " ":
        row3[0] = "O"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        x_turn()
    if row == "3" and column == "2" and row3[1] == " ":
        row3[1] = "O"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        x_turn()
    if row == "3" and column == "3" and row3[2] == " ":
        row3[2] = "O"
        draw_matrix()
        check_game()
        end_game()
        x_turn()
print "End of Game!"
x_turn()
```

Comment: Fix all the indentation first

Comment: first time posting to this site and first time asking a coding question. I tried to fix the indentation as best as i could. Do you guys just copy paste your code from notepad ++? When i did it didn't give me the forums code block. Let me know the best way.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because all the following variables need to be declared with keyword global otherwise, inside a function it'll be considered as a local variable

```
global matrix =[]

global row1 = [" ", " ", " "]
global row2 = [" ", " ", " "]
global row3 = [" ", " ", " "]
global row1check = False
global row2check = False
global row3check = False
```

And also, while using them in function, first to make python understand it's same as the global variable, define it again in function definition as global row1, etc.

```
def check_game () :
global row1check
global row2check
global row3check
global row1
global row2
global row3
if not " " in row1:
    row1check = True
    print row1check
if " " not in row2:
    row2check = True
if " " not in row3:
    row3check = True
```

Hence, rewrite the whole code keeping in mind about global variables.

Comment: Yes sir that was the answer. 'global row1
row1 = [" ", " ", " "]'

Comment: @Thomas if the answer is useful, please UpVote it as well, as StackOverflow users might be confused/bothered with the downvote on the answer.